# Use ReactJS in ASP.Net Core without React.ASPNet library

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

In one of my asp.net core project, I want to use ReactJS. Can anyone suggest me that how to implemen ReactJS without using ReactJS.net library (https://reactjs.net/)?

I have tried but getting an error in JSX file. I have already installed JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.

My App.jsx file is as given below, only a single statement

ReactDOM.render(test,
    document.getElementById('divNew'));

I took the reference of App.jsx file in About.cshtml , after adding react and react-dom references. But getting the following error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

**EDIT :**

*I was able to solve my problem by adding Babel , a java script compiler.*

I added the below given lines in About.cshtml, where I want to render UI using ReactJS. Before this I also added the reference of React and React-DOM.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="~/ClientApp/App.jsx">
</script>
```

This solves my problem and can be helpful for others. However, in developer tool I am getting a warning

"You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production"

To handle this warning, we can use any option defined on the below given link

https://babeljs.io/en/setup/

Hope this will help others :-)

Comment: you only need React.net project if you want to do serverside rendering of components else, like you use jquery you can use react on client side by adding the bundle file as script to you page.

Comment: its a client side library doesnt care wht is used serverside

Comment: See I have updated my question. I want to generate view in asp.net core with React JS.But the problem seems that JSX is not converting into JS files.

Comment: I found the solution of my problem and hope this will help others. I have added solution in question. If anyone has any better solution , post that.